# Which type is considered to be a FormData when handled from ajax.post to java through struts 2?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

I haven´t found any answer in the forum, however it's possible the question has yet been asked. Sorry in advance, if that's the case.
Basically, I'm creating a FormData object in a jsp to capture an uploaded file and I would like to access it in my java Dispatcher. I tried the type FormData in java, but it looks like it doesnt exist.
Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the .jsp code:

```
var file_data = $("#fileUpload").prop("files")[0];   
   var file_name = $("#fileUpload").val();
   var form_data = new FormData();                  
   form_data.append("file", file_data);              
   form_data.append("fileName", file_name);  

       $.post('crearNuevaActa.action',
    {
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    data: form_data,
    }
```

Comment: Any code would be appreciated

Comment: Yes, I'm using Struts 2

Comment: Read about `FormData`. E.g. this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects.

Comment: Sorry, looks like I've expressed myself badly, I'm looking for the way to call to the object form_data in a .java class

Comment: I don't understand. The request parameters will be available as any other form parameters are.

Comment: @GreenPyramid `form_data` is a javascript object, there's no type converter available to convert it to java.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your formData to JSON

```
var myFormData = JSON.stringify(form_data);
```

on your jQuery post change data to:

```
data:  "data:"+data,
```

On your action class include following,

```
private List<MyBean> data;

//setter and getter
```

Define MyBean POJO class;

```
class MyBean{
//include  file filename and any other field you have 
//getter setter
}
```

configure your action class to deserialize JSON

```
<action name="" class="">
    <result type="json"/>
  <interceptor-ref name="json">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
</action>
```